# How to get SUM and JOIN across multiple tables to work properly. Wrong results returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

There are 5 tables that are being queried.

1. Assignments (table that assigns clients to auditors)
2. AssignmentCarriers (List of carriers and their settings. linked to assignments)
3. Auditors (people)
4. Clients
5. Claims (claims entered by an auditor on behalf of the client)
6. Entries (each claim can have multiple entries. This is where we get the $$ from)

Here's the scenario. Management can **Assign** a **client** to an **auditor**. That auditor can open **claims** for his clients to try to make $$.

I have to find out what clients an auditor was assigned and what claims he has opened between a specific time period and how much total $$ was returned. Here's my code. I'll paste it twice so that you can see what it looks like un-commented and commented. Then I'll show what my current results are. I just can't seem to figure out what is off here.

**interrupted code**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  a.clientID, 
  code,
  SUM(case when cl.dateon >='1/1/2020' AND cl.dateon < '1/3/2020' AND entries.errorCode NOT IN('DP','RB','DN','WP','WA','CE','RC','SI','CI','PE','OV') AND status='closed' AND cl.client=code then entries.refundDue else 0.0 end) as JanRC20,   
  SUM(case when cl.dateon >='1/1/2020' AND cl.dateon < '1/3/2020' AND entries.errorCode IN('DP','RB','DN','WP','WA','CE','RC','SI','CI','PE','OV') AND status='closed' AND cl.client=code then entries.refundDue else 0.0 end) as JanPC20

FROM assignments a 

INNER JOIN clients c ON c.clientID=a.clientID 
INNER JOIN AssignmentCarriers ac ON ac.acID=a.acID 
INNER JOIN claims cl ON cl.auditorID=a.auditorID
INNER JOIN entries ON entries.rID=cl.rID


WHERE a.auditorID=101 AND isAssignment='True' AND active='True' AND pos=1

GROUP BY a.clientID, code

ORDER BY code
```

Commented Code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.clientID, 
  code,-- being an older database, the uniqueID here is the code, not clientID
  SUM(case when cl.dateon >='1/1/2020' AND cl.dateon < '1/3/2020' AND entries.errorCode NOT IN('DP','RB','DN','WP','WA','CE','RC','SI','CI','PE','OV') AND status='closed' AND cl.client=code then entries.refundDue else 0.0 end) as JanRC20, -- this is supposed to SUM up the "refundDue" for the specified time period for claims that have a status of closed and does not have a specific errorCode.
  SUM(case when cl.dateon >='1/1/2020' AND cl.dateon < '1/3/2020' AND entries.errorCode IN('DP','RB','DN','WP','WA','CE','RC','SI','CI','PE','OV') AND status='closed' AND cl.client=code then entries.refundDue else 0.0 end) as JanPC20 -- same as the previous but this includes the specified errorCodes

FROM assignments a 

INNER JOIN clients c ON c.clientID=a.clientID -- this brings in the code from the clients table and whether it's active or not (bool)
INNER JOIN AssignmentCarriers ac ON ac.acID=a.acID -- for checking if isAssignments='True'
INNER JOIN claims cl ON cl.auditorID=a.auditorID -- brings in claims table
INNER JOIN entries ON entries.rID=cl.rID -- brings in entries table


WHERE a.auditorID=101 AND isAssignment='True' AND active='True' AND pos=1 -- only return results where a specified auditor (101) is assigned

GROUP BY a.clientID, code

ORDER BY code
```

I feel like I'm close but it doesn't work. When I run the code, I do absolutely get a list of all of this auditors assigned clients. That's working fine. What's off is the $$ amount. So, focusing on 1 client that this auditor is assigned, here's the result:

```
clientID.  code.   JanRC20.   JanPC20. 
678        INCM   8007.2382    0.0000
```

When I run a query directly on the claims/entries table with WHERE auditorID=101 and then for the specified dates and code, it's true that JanPC20 = 0 BUT JanRC20 = 2669.0794.

There's actually only 1 record returned and the "2669.0794" is the amount in the refundDue column. What is going on here?

Comment: Best thing to do here is to try and run the code without the SUMs and GROUP BY line.  Comment out the GROUP BY line, take out the "SUM(...)", leave in the CASE selects.  Then you should be able to see all the rows that are going to be summed. From there you should be able to narrow down why it is summing so many rows. Your joins are causing the amount you expect to be trippled (8007=2669*3), so one of your joins is returning 3 rows.

Comment: 8007.2382 y exactly 3 times  2669.0794, there must be a join missing some condition, making the only one record you are expecting to be counted three times.

Comment: @MundoPeter Either this, or like mentioned in the comments the ClientId is not Unique. If it’s that, you could try to drop ClientId and only group by code. Then the distinct should work correctly.

Comment: k... i think i know what's causing the problem. In the assignments table, he's being assigned the same client multiple times...y? because each client has carriers attached to them. A client can have 100's of carriers in this case, the auditor is in charge of 3 carriers of the 1 client. It's still the 1 client we want because claims are opened based on clients, not carriers. 

Comment: i'm trying to approach this a different way, but not sure if there's a way i can do this in SQL alone. Is there a way to get the desired result (table above) BUT in 2 steps. So, the first step would get all the clients that the auditor is assigned to. Once i have those client id's, then proceed to querying the claims table. I already know how to get the clientID's on their own, but how to combine the 2. Basically generate the 2nd query based on the first one's results... i think. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following and see what is being tripled:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  a.clientID, 
  code,
  case when cl.dateon >='1/1/2020' AND cl.dateon < '1/3/2020' AND entries.errorCode NOT IN('DP','RB','DN','WP','WA','CE','RC','SI','CI','PE','OV') AND status='closed' AND cl.client=code then entries.refundDue else 0.0 end as JanRC20,   
  case when cl.dateon >='1/1/2020' AND cl.dateon < '1/3/2020' AND entries.errorCode IN('DP','RB','DN','WP','WA','CE','RC','SI','CI','PE','OV') AND status='closed' AND cl.client=code then entries.refundDue else 0.0 end as JanPC20

, a.assignmentID
, c.clientID
, ac.acID
, cl.claimID
, a.auditorID
, entries.rID

FROM assignments a 

INNER JOIN clients c ON c.clientID=a.clientID 
INNER JOIN AssignmentCarriers ac ON ac.acID=a.acID 
INNER JOIN claims cl ON cl.auditorID=a.auditorID
INNER JOIN entries ON entries.rID=cl.rID


WHERE a.auditorID=101 AND isAssignment='True' AND active='True' AND pos=1

--GROUP BY a.clientID, code

ORDER BY code
```

This will return 3 rows. The ID columns which return the same IDs for all 3 rows aren't a problem.  The ID columns which have different values are the problem.  The table that those IDs are coming from is the table with multiple values.  You may need to do a further consolidation on that table to get the values you want.

Comment: k... i think i know what's causing the problem. In the assignments table, he's being assigned the same client multiple times...y? because each client has carriers attached to them. A client can have 100's of carriers in this case, the auditor is in charge of 3 carriers of this 1 client.. It's still the 1 client we want because claims are opened based on clients, not carriers. 

Comment: i'm trying to approach this a different way, but not sure if there's a way i can do this in SQL alone. Is there a way to get the desired result (table above) BUT in 2 steps. So, the first step would get all the clients that the auditor is assigned to. Once i have those client id's, then proceed to querying the claims table. I already know how to get the clientID's on their own, but how to combine the 2. Basically generate the 2nd query based on the first one's results... i think. Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you just take AssignmentCarriers out of your first query then? As it's not used to return anything, nor used for further joining, just remove this join:
INNER JOIN AssignmentCarriers ac ON ac.acID=a.acID

Comment: AssignmentCarriers brings in the "isAssignment" part of the Where clause. Also, even if i removed it, the Assignments table has 3 records in there for each AssignmentCarrier so it would yield the same results